# MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, mapkit

How do I add this button to my `UIViewController` on a bottom navigation bar I made via Interface Builder?  I'm not sure how to use this class as the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserTrackingBarButtonItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) isn't very good on it...